# Populating Pandas DataFrame with Incomplete Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create an F-Table for an Anova test. I have my values already like this:

```
data = [[ssBetween,ssWithin,ssTotal],[dfbetween,dfwithin,dftotal], [msBetween,msWithin],[F]]
index = ['Between','Total','Within']
columns = ['SS','df','MS','F']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=columns)
df['SS'] = data[0]
df['df'] = data[1]
df['MS'] = data[2]
df['F'] = data[3]
```

When I run i get this error:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

I understand I could just fill in the missing values with zeros or something but I wanted to learn a more pythonic way to do this. I just want to fill the table in with the values I have and leave the rest of the spaces in the table as null values.

Answer (score 1):

Just using adding your data

```
pd.DataFrame(data = data,index = columns,columns = index).T
Out[149]: 
                SS         df         MS     F
Between  ssBetween  dfbetween  msBetween     F
Total     ssWithin   dfwithin   msWithin  None
Within     ssTotal    dftotal       None  None
```

Comment: Smart :) The only funny thing is it seems that `Total` and `Within` are misplaced (is his example too)